# jqgrid is not loading when searching by passing javascript object to asp.net webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

Hi tried to load the jqgrid with json by passing javascript object. but the grid is not loading.
Below is my javascript code

```
 oSearchParam = {
                InvoiceNo: document.getElementById('txtInvoiceNumber').value,


            }


            var grid = $("#dataGrid")[0];




            //my code
            $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
                // setup custom parameter names to pass to server
                prmNames: {
                    rows: "numRows",
                    page: "page",
                    sort: "sortField",
                    order: "sortOrder"

                },
                // add by default to avoid webmethod parameter conflicts
              //  postData: { oSearchParam: oSearchParam },
                // setup ajax call to webmethod
                datatype: function (postdata) {
                    $(".loading").show(); // make sure we can see loader text
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'InvoiceSearch.aspx/GetSearchResultData',
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                        dataType: "json",                      
                        success: function (data, st) {
                            if (st == "success") {
                                var grid = $("#dataGrid")[0];
                                alert(data.d);
                                grid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(data.d));
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error with AJAX callback");
                        }
                    });
                },
                // this is what jqGrid is looking for in json callback
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "totalpages",
                    records: "totalrecords",
                    cell: "cell",
                    id: "id", //index of the column with the PK in it 

                    repeatitems: true
                },
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                height: 'auto',
                colNames: ['InvoiceNo'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'InvoiceNo', index: 'InvoiceNo', width: 55, search: false }


                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: jQuery("#pagingGrid"),
                sortname: "InvoiceNo",
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Grid Title Here",
                gridComplete: function () {
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagingGrid', { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
            {}, // default settings for edit
            {}, // add
            {}, // delete
            { closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, //search
            {}
        )
```

And below is the webmethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetSearchResultData(int? numRows, int? page, string sortField, string sortOrder, SearchParam oSearchParam)
    {

 DataTable dtInvoiceList = Mymethod();

        var query = dtInvoiceList.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(i => new SearchParam
                   {
                       InvoiceNo = i.Field<string>("InvoiceNo"),
                       // ImageId =  i.Field<string>("DocID"),
                       InvoiceAmount = i.Field<decimal>("Amount"),
                       // ImageId = i.Field<string>("DocID"),
                       Status = i.Field<string>("Status"),
                       CurrentlyWith = i.Field<string>("CurrentlyWith")

                   }).ToList();


        //--- setup calculations
        int pageIndex = page ?? 1; //--- current page
        int pageSize = numRows ?? 10; //--- number of rows to show per page
        int totalRecords = query.Count(); //--- number of total items from query
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalRecords / (decimal)pageSize); //--- number of pages

        var sortedRecords = query
            .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize) //--- page the data
            .Take(pageSize).ToList();

        //--- format json
        var jsonData = new
        {
            totalpages = totalPages, //--- number of pages
            page = pageIndex, //--- current page
            totalrecords = totalRecords, //--- total items
            rows = (
                from row1 in sortedRecords
                select new
                {
                    i = row1.ImageId,
                    cell = new string[] {
                        row1.InvoiceNo, 
                         row1.Status,
                         row1.CurrentlyWith,
                       row1.InvoiceAmount.ToString(),

                    }
                }
           ).ToArray()
        };

        string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData);
        return result;
}
```

My webmethod is not getting called.
Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: The code of both sides (the server code and the JavaScript code) contain really many errors. Do you get some very old code example? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? It's important to know the total number of rows in the `dtInvoiceList` (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000). The main error in the server code - the usage of manual JSON serialization. The main error in the client code - the usage of `datatype` defined as function.

Comment: Can you please tell me where are the errors.And why the datatype property is wrong.

Comment: Could you answer on my questions (see the previous comment)? For example, how many total items of data (invoices) you need to display in the grid.

Comment: want to display 20 200 500(paging dropdown)

Comment: I asked for the **total number of rows**, not for the page size. jqGrid allows to use `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` (free jqGrid only). It allows to simplify the server code and to improve the response time of the client. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) displays 4000 rows, 13 columns in 20 rows in the page. You can see the time of loading, local sorting and filtering. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) displayes 40000 rows and it's slowly.

Comment: What is unique id which you use in the database table `dtInvoiceList`? You use `i = row1.ImageId` in your current code, instead of `id = ...` and the `ImageId` property is **not filled** in the above code. It's unclear whether `ImageId` or `InvoiceNo` values are different (unique) in every returned items.